# Definition of Convex Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Spivak's book states first this definition of Convex Function:

**Definition 1:**

> A function $f$ is convex on an interval, if for all $a$ and $b$ in the interval, the line segment joining $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$ lies above the graph of $f$.

Now, this means that the stright line defined by the function $g(x)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)+f(a)$ is such that $f(x)<g(x)$. But this is equivalent to say that $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. This is the reason why then it states an equivalent definition.

**Definition 2:**

> A function $f$ is convex on an interval if for $a$, $x$, and $b$ in the interval with $a<x<b$ we have $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

Now, analogously, I can take the same stright line defined by $g$ but now described by the function $G(x)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-b)+f(b)$ in such a way that, if $f$ is convex by definition $(1)$, then $f(x)<G(x)$ and therefore

**RESULT:**  $\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ because $x-b <0$.

My question is then, how can I get this result from definition $2)$?.

Comment: Are you asking why definition 2 implies definition 1?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I'm supossing they're equivalent, just like Spivak's book says. The thing is that if both are equivalent then I can get this result that I've gotten from definition 1) by only using definition 2).

Comment: As the joke goes, let's choke the fire and pour the water out. You take the definition 2, derive the definition 1, then use it to establish the desired result.

Comment: I agree with TZakrevskiy and I'm not sure what the question really is. If you understand that Definition 1 and Definition 2 are equivalent and can prove this, there should be no issues.

Comment: @AdamRubinson It was just for fun supposing for example that Spivak  wouldn't say that both definitions are equivalent and stated definition 2 as given then I'd like to prove not definition 1 but the result mencioned above (the one that I got from definition 1 by using the function G) without using definition 1. Anyway you both are right that this is unnecessary if one already knows that both definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Which "result"? The first sentence after Definition 1?

Comment: @AdamRubinson After definition 2. I just made an edit to mark it as result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with definition 2, $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. Cross multiply (both denominators positive) and break-up:
$$\left[f(x)-f(a)\right](b-a)<\left[f(b)-f(a)\right](x-a)$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x)(b-a)-f(a)b+f(a)a < \left[f(b)-f(a)\right]x-f(b)a+f(a)a $$
Cancel out $f(a)a$ from both sides, move  $f(b)a$ from RHS to LHS and subtract from both sides $b\left[f(b)-f(a)\right]$:
$$\Rightarrow f(x)(b-a)-f(a)b + f(b)a-b\left[f(b)-f(a)\right] < \left[f(b)-f(a)\right]x-b\left[f(b)-f(a)\right] $$

Simplify and collect terms  :$$f(x)(b-a) - f(b)(b-a) < \left[f(b)-f(a)\right](x-b)$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
because $x-b$ is negative.

Answer (score 2):

This is an outline of an "obvious" proof. You can fill in the details if you wish.

Fix a and b in the interval with a < b and assume the meaning of "convex" as in Definition 2 to be correct.

Take any point x with a < x < b and draw three straight lines. The first straight line (Line 1) joins a to x. The second straight line (Line 2) joins x to b. The third straight line (Line 3) joins a to b.

Definition 2 says that Line 1 has lesser gradient than Line 3.

Now you want to show that the Line 2 has *larger* gradient than Line 3.

Line 1 has lesser gradient than Line 3. Suppose Line 2 has gradient less than or equal to the gradient of Line 3. Then Line 2 cannot intersect Line 3 at b, a contradiction.

For proof of "Then Line 2 cannot intersect Line 3 at b" just consider that f(x) < g(x) and draw two lines, each of gradient (f(b) - f(a)) / (b - a): one starting at (x,f(x)) and one starting at (x,g(x)).